# Why is Rails wrapping my scoped arguments in parentheses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, mysql2

I'm creating a `UserSession` model for my application, with a scope `active` for sessions active in the last week.

Everything is working correctly up to my attempts to use the application after logging in - I am able to log in and create a session, and it's able to find my user by `user_id`. However, Rails is generating SQL that returns no sessions, so I can't actually use the application.

This is the relevant code of the model:

```
scope :active, -> { where('accessed_at >= ?', 2.weeks.ago) 

def self.authenticate(key)
    self.active.find_by(key: key)
end
```

And this is the generated SQL when I call `UserSession.authenticate('123345')`

```
SELECT  `user_sessions`.* FROM `user_sessions`  WHERE `user_sessions`.`key` = '123345' AND (accessed_at >= '2013-10-12 10:50:52') LIMIT 1
```

As shown above, it wraps the conditions from the scope lambda in parentheses, which makes the SQL valid but not returning the necessary data. Is there any way to make the `scope` without parentheses?

Comment: what difference will it make if you remove the parentheses...removing the parentheses gives u the desired data??

Comment: what parentheses do you have in mind? I can see _one_ pair of parentheses in the SQL and they have _zero_ effect on semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated SQL is semantically correct. Rails wraps each level of scope in its own set of parenthesis in order to ensure correct execution order.

There is no difference between the following when executed:

```
SELECT  `user_sessions`.* FROM `user_sessions` WHERE `user_sessions`.`key` = '123345' AND (accessed_at >= '2013-10-12 10:50:52') LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT  `user_sessions`.* FROM `user_sessions`  WHERE `user_sessions`.`key` = '123345' AND accessed_at >= '2013-10-12 10:50:52' LIMIT 1
```

Are you sure that there is a record that satisfies that query?

Comment: Shit, after I looked at it a little deeper it actually turned out to be changing the session token on each update because I had set a `before_validation` filter to generate a new token. You're completely right, and it wasn't finding a valid record. Thanks!